# Regex to match words following a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I don't know how to phrase the title, so I will be doing the explaining here. I have sample text like this:

> Line 1
> Contents and text in the line.
> It's a paragraph.
>
> Line 2
> Those for this line.
> Another paragraph
>
> Line 3
> More contents.
>
> Line 4
> More contents...

How do I extract the paragraphs? I tried this:
`(?:Line \d{1,3})(.*?)(?:Line \d{1,3})`

This matched odd numbered paragraphs, like paragraphs 1, 3, 5 etc.
I'm working with C# but this is regex, so I don't think there will be any major difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pattern which should work:

```
(Line \d+.*?)(?=Line|$)
```

This says to match a paragraph beginning with `Line`, followed by anything up until hitting the start of the next paragraph (i.e. `Line`) *or* the end of the text.  The end of the text would occur for the last paragraph.

You would also need to run this regex in dot all mode, or, if not, replace the `.*` with `[\s\S]*`.

### Demo

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tried it yet but reading, I know it should work.

Comment: This will not really work, if you have the word "Line" somewhere in the paragraph. Also it will select the line with "Line" pattern, which i think the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Actually, it will work for my particular situation. The text I'm matching certainly doesn't contain the `Line \d` pattern. In fact, in my app, it is not `Line...`; it's another word which doesn't occur in the matching text. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select only the text without the "Line \d" pattern, you can use this.
This is a fine tuning on your regex:

```
(?:Line \d+\n)(.*?)(?=\nLine \d+\n|$)
```

[Check It](https://regex101.com/r/4u4A4w/1)

Because we cant use the wild card in look behind, i used like you did the non-capturing group, and choosing the text until we hit the Line pattern again or end of file.

Comment: You are right. Actually, I'm still not sure whether to include the `Line \d` pattern.